# Python: How to replace old uploaded files to Google Drive

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have this script written in python which looks thrue folder 'CSVtoGD', list every CSV there and send those CSV's as independent sheets to my google drive. I am trying to write a line which will delete the old files when I run the program again. What am I missing here? I am trying to achieve that by using:

```
sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(filename.split(".")[0]+" TTF")
```

Unfortunately the script is doing the same thing after adding this line. It is uploading new files but not deleting old ones.

Whole script looks like that

```
import gspread
import os
gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/user/credentials.json')

os.chdir('/users/user/CSVtoGD')

files = os.listdir()

for filename in files:
   if filename.split(".")[1] == "csv":
      folder_id = '19vrbvaeDqWcxFGwPV82APWYTmB'
      sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(filename.split(".")[0]+" TTF")
      sh = gc.create(filename.split(".")[0]+" TTF", folder_id)
      content = open(filename, 'r').read().encode('utf-8') 
      gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```

Everything is working fine, CSVs from folder are uploaded to google drive, my problem is with deleting the old CSV (with the same name as new ones)

Comment: Could you share the part of code where you are deleting the old file and uploading the new one? Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the document of gspread, it seems that the argument of the method of `del_spreadsheet` is the file ID. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/client.html?highlight=del_spreadsheet#gspread.Client.del_spreadsheet) When I saw your script, you are using the filename as the argument. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(filename.split(".")[0]+" TTF")
```

#### To:

```
sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(gc.open(filename.split(".")[0] + " TTF").id)
```

#### Note:

- When the Spreadsheet of the filename of `filename.split(".")[0] + " TTF"` is not existing, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [del_spreadsheet(file_id)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/client.html?highlight=del_spreadsheet#gspread.Client.del_spreadsheet)

### Added:

From your reply of [`When I try do delete other file using this method from My Drive it is working well.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72450352/python-how-to-replace-old-uploaded-files-to-google-drive/72454984#comment128007228_72454984), it was found that my proposed modification can be used for "My Drive". But, it seems that this cannot be used for the shared drive.

When I saw the script of gspread again, I noticed that the current request cannot search the files in the shared drive using the filename. And also, I confirmed that in the current gspread, the Spreadsheet ID cannot be retrieved using gspread. Because the files cannot be searched from all shared drives. By this, I would like to propose the following modified script.

#### Modified script:

```py
import gspread
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/user/credentials.json')

service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=gc.auth)


def getSpreadsheetId(filename):
    q = f"name='{filename}' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed=false" # or q = "name='" + filename + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed=false"
    res = service.files().list(q=q, fields="files(id)", corpora="allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
    items = res.get("files", [])
    if not items:
        print("No files found.")
        exit()
    return items[0]["id"]


os.chdir('/users/user/CSVtoGD')

files = os.listdir()

for filename in files:
    fname = filename.split(".")
    if fname[1] == "csv":
        folder_id = '19vrbvaeDqWcxFGwPV82APWYTmB'
        oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0] + " TTF")
        sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)
        sh = gc.create(fname[0] + " TTF", folder_id)
        content = open(filename, "r").read().encode("utf-8")
        gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```

- In this modification, in order to retrieve the Spreadsheet ID from the filename in the shared drive, googleapis for python is used. [Ref](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)
- But, in this case, it supposes that you have the permission for writing to the shared drive. Please be careful about this.

Comment: When I modify the script to `sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(open(filename.split(".")[0] + " TTF").id)` I got error saying that there is no "first name of csv" - but there is the file as I can see it in Google Drive. Maybe there is missing something that specifies the folder of the files in Google Drive?

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Now, I noticed my miscopied my script. I wrote `sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(client.open(filename.split(".")[0] + " TTF").id)`. In this case, `client` is `gc` in the case of your script. So, please test `sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(gc.open(filename.split(".")[0] + " TTF").id)`. But, in your reply, you use `sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(open(filename.split(".")[0] + " TTF").id)`. In this case, I think that `open(filename.split(".")[0] + " TTF").id` doesn't work. Please be careful about this.

Comment: thanks for replying. Yes I changed the line to gc.open but now I got `code': 403, 'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.'`. When I try do delete other file using this method from My Drive it is working well. There is a problem with the localization of the files to delete because they are in Shared Drives. So as I can see I can upload to shared drives but can not delete? hm.. Is there any way to repair that error? Add some permissions to me on Shared Drive?

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice that you were using the shared Drive from your question. But, when I saw the script of gspread, it seems that `open` uses `"supportsAllDrives": True` and `"includeItemsFromAllDrives": True,`, [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/bb4e9f12ed28e28d1e473c9fbc9c0046482dfb7b/gspread/client.py#L88) and `del_spreadsheet` uses `"supportsAllDrives": True`. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/bb4e9f12ed28e28d1e473c9fbc9c0046482dfb7b/gspread/client.py#L360)

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer From this situation, when your client can access to the shared drive, using the above modification, I think that you can retrieve the spreadsheet ID and delete it. So, can you confirm your permission again? But, from `When I try do delete other file using this method from My Drive it is working well.`, it was found when you have the permission, this modification works. I'm glad for it.

Comment: To a user who voted down. Could you please tell me the modification point in my answer? I would like to study from it.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer When I saw the script of gspread, I noticed that the current request cannot search the files in the shared drive using the filename. And also, I confirmed that in the current gspread, the Spreadsheet ID cannot be retrieved using gspread. So, in order to retrieve the spreadsheet ID from the filename in the shared drive, I added a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In this modified script, I could confirm that the script worked.

Comment: thank you for your help. Unfortunately after doing your modifications, I still get an error 403 "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file" ..

Comment: Maybe I am missing something? some scopes? hmm.. that's weird that I can upload files but as I can see there is no way of deleting them (thrue python/gspread etc. ofc)

Comment: I mean in Shared Drive of course I get that error

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my additional sample script for both the shared drive and my Google Drive, no error occurs. I apologize for this. In this case, I'm worried your permission for the shared drive. So, can you confirm that your client has permission for writing to the shared drive again? By the way, about `I still get an error 403 "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file"`, where does the error occur in my sample script?

Comment: hello, the error is: `sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)` I have permission to write because my previous script witch uploads CSVs to Shared Drive is working properly. I just can not delete those files from shared drives which is interesting..

Comment: Do I have to add scopes to my script maybe? I am pretty amateur in python and google drive API :(

Comment: If I delete just one row of your file: `sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)` there are no errors and the script is just uploading new CSV without deleting old ones.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. From `the error is: sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)`, I could confirm that my sample script for retrieving the Spreadsheet ID from the filename worked fine. About the error of `gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)`, when I saw the script of `gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)` of gspread, the script works for the shared drive. And also, now I tested `gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)` using the shared Drive, no error occurs.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer  And, from `the script is just uploading new CSV without deleting old ones.`, it seems that you have the permission for writing. So, in this case, can you add your current script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what is your request. I am using the same script as you have wrote.

Comment: And the error I get is `APIError: {'code': 403, 'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.', 'errors': [{'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientFilePermissions'}]}`

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. From `Sorry, I don't quite understand what is your request. I am using the same script as you have wrote.`, when I used my proposed script. No error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. And from `'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.'`, I'm worried that you might have no permission for deleting the file. Can you confirm this? And, I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: thank you for your help so far. no problem about English :p But the problem is I don't understand why I don't have permission to delete the file :( owner of shared drive is telling me that I can do everything with files in it..

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. About `But the problem is I don't understand why I don't have permission to delete the file :( owner of the shared drive is telling me that I can do everything with files in it`, I think so. Because when I tested my sample script, the script worked fine. So, I cannot understand your current situation. For example, when you check `oldSpreadsheetId`, the Spreadsheet ID is from the Spreadsheet you can access? For example, there are the same filenames and you cannot write the file of the ID? I'm worried about this.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer If there are the same filenames of `fname[0] + " TTF"`, please test my sample script using a unique filename.

Comment: hmm.. when I change the `sh = gc.del_Spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)` to `sh = gc.del_Spreadsheet('nameoffile')` I get error `There is no file nameoffile.` The dot at the end worries me. In the filename there is no dot..

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. About `hmm.. when I change the sh = gc.del_Spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId) to sh = gc.del_Spreadsheet('nameoffile') I get error There is no file nameoffile. The dot at the end worries me. In the filename there is no dot..`, I have to apologize for my very poor English skill. In my answer, first, I have mentioned the argument of `del_Spreadsheet`. In this case, it is required to use the Spreadsheet ID. But, now, it seems that you are using the filename as the Spreadsheet ID. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer From your reply, I'm worried that you might still have used the Spreadsheet name as the Spreadsheet ID. When the Spreadsheet ID is of the Spreadsheet used for `gc.del_Spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)`, the script works. So, in order to confirm your current situation, could you please add your current script to your question?

Comment: I can not add script to comments as there are to many arguments and it does not make sense. I am using copy paste to your answer, the same script :)

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. About `I can not add script to comments as there are to many arguments and it does not make sense. I am using copy paste to your answer, the same script :)`, I have to apologize fo my poor English skill again. Can I ask you whether you can understand my English? Because it seems that you are using Spreadsheet name as the Spreadsheet ID from `when I change the sh = gc.del_Spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId) to sh = gc.del_Spreadsheet('nameoffile') I get error There is no file nameoffile.`. How about this?

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer For example, can you test using directly the Spreadsheet ID to `gc.del_Spreadsheet("###spreadsheetID###")`?  You can see about the Spreadsheet ID at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts When you have the write permission to the Spreadsheet of the Spreadsheet ID, I think that the script works. If this can be done, the script works. If this was the same issue, please check the permission again.

Comment: Hello once again! Your solution works great. As I thought, I didn't get enough permission on shared drive. Now it is working great. Thank you very much :P

Comment: hello again. I have been working with your script and it is working great. Thank u one more time :) I have tho one more question. Do you know a solution to my problem: when I add some file to folder CSVtoGD and this filename wasn't in the google drive, I got a error "list index out of range" It is caused because the script is looking at files in folder CSVtoGD and then looks for ID of CSV in google drive named as files in Google Drive. It there a to make the script work in this situation and just ignore the file which is not in google drive?

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer I would like to support you and your new question. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.

Comment: hello, I have made another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72572901/google-api-python-delete-old-files-in-google-drive-by-filename-in-local-folder :)