# Google API/Python: Delete old files in Google Drive by filename in local folder, upload new filenames from local folder

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a problem witch was hard to write in the title. I have this script with a lot of help from @Tanaike . This script is doing basically two things:

1. Deletes files from Google Drive folder by filenames which are in local folder CSVtoGD (using spreadsheet ID's)

then:

2. Upload list of CSV from local folder "CSVtoGD" to Google Drive folder

I have a big problem now and can not work it out. The script is deleting old files in google drive when there are the same filenames in CSVtoGD. When I add new file to local folder CSVtoGD, there is a error "list index out of range" and I got printed "No files found" like in the script. I was trying to make some modification but it was blind shoots. What I want this script to do is to delete from Google Drive folder ONLY files which are in local CSVtoGD folder and work on with rest of the files in CSVtoGD (just upload them). Anyone have some answer to that? Thank you :)

```
import gspread
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/user/credentials.json')

service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=gc.auth)


def getSpreadsheetId(filename):
    q = "name='" + filename + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed=false"
    res = service.files().list(q=q, fields="files(id)", corpora="allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
    items = res.get("files", [])
    if not items:
        print("No files found.")
        exit()
    return items[0]["id"]


os.chdir('/users/user/CSVtoGD2')

files = os.listdir()


for filename in files:
    fname = filename.split(".")
    if fname[1] == "csv":
      folder_id = '1z_pUvZyt5AoTNy-aKCKLmlNjdR2OPo'
      oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0])
      #print(oldSpreadsheetId)
      sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)
**# IF there are the same filenames in CSVtoGD folder on my Mac 
#and the same filenames on Google Drive folder, 
#those lines works well. 
#Problem is when there are new files in CSVtoGD local folder on Mac.**
      sh = gc.create(fname[0], folder_id)
      content = open(filename, "r").read().encode("utf-8")
      gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```

Comment: About `The script is deleting old files in google drive when there are the same filenames in CSVtoGD.`, when I saw your showing script, the file is not deleted. And, it seems that `sh` is not declared. From this situation, I'm worried that you miscopied your current script for replicating your current issue. How about this?

Comment: I have edited the file. It is deleting, it is uploading. But it is not working when there is new file in CSVtoGD folder which was not in Google Drive folder before

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, for example, when `sample.csv` is existing on your local PC and a Spreadsheet of `sample` is existing in your Google Drive, you want to delete the Spreadsheet of `sample` from your Google Drive. And, when `sample1.csv` is existing on your local PC and the Spreadsheet of `sample1` is NOT existing in your Google Drive, you don't want to do anything. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: By the way, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue of `list index out of range`? Because, in your showing script, when the filename of the local PC is not existing in Google Drive, the script is finished. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. By correctly understanding your question, I would like to think of a solution. I apologize that I would like to try to correctly understand your question.

Comment: yes thank you for your help. What I want to do: when sample.csv is existing on my local PC and a Spreadsheet of sample is existing in my Google Drive, i want to delete the Spreadsheet of sample from my Google Drive. And, when sample1.csv is existing on my local PC and the Spreadsheet of sample1 is NOT existing in my Google Drive, I want to upload the sample1  to my Google Drive but it is not working in this situation and then I got error "list out of range"

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `And, when sample1.csv is existing on my local PC and the Spreadsheet of sample1 is NOT existing in my Google Drive, I want to upload the sample1 to my Google Drive`, in this case, you want to upload the file as a CSV file?

Comment: Yes, as a csv, just like before

Comment: By guessing your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: From `Yes, as a csv, just like before`, in this case, please remove `"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",` from `file_metadata` in my modified script. By this, the CSV file is uploaded as the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- For example, when `sample.csv` is existing on your local PC and a Spreadsheet of `sample` is existing in your Google Drive, you want to delete the Spreadsheet of `sample` from your Google Drive.
- When `sample1.csv` is existing on your local PC and the Spreadsheet of `sample1` is NOT existing in your Google Drive, you want to upload `sample1.csv` to Google Drive.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
import gspread
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/user/credentials.json')
service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=gc.auth)
folder_id = '1z_pUvZyt5AoTNy-aKCKLmlNjdR2OPo'  # Please set the folder ID you want to upload the file.


def getSpreadsheetId(filename, filePath):
    q = "name='" + filename + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed=false"
    res = service.files().list(q=q, fields="files(id)", corpora="allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
    items = res.get("files", [])
    if not items:
        print("No files found.")
        
        file_metadata = {
            "name": filename,
            "parents": [folder_id],
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
        }
        media = MediaFileUpload(filePath + "/" + filename + ".csv")
        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id").execute()
        id = file.get("id")
        print("File was uploaded. The file ID is " + id)
        exit()

    return items[0]["id"]


filePath = '/users/user/CSVtoGD2'
os.chdir(filePath)

files = os.listdir()

for filename in files:
    fname = filename.split(".")
    if fname[1] == "csv":
        oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0], filePath)
        print(oldSpreadsheetId)
        sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)
        sh = gc.create(fname[0], folder_id)
        content = open(filename, "r").read().encode("utf-8")
        gc.import_csv(sh.id, content)
```

- When this script is run, the above flow is run.

#### Note:

- In this modification, the CSV file is uploaded as a Google Spreadsheet. From your question, I thought that this might be your expected result. But, if you want to upload the CSV file as the CSV file, please remove `"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",` from `file_metadata`.
- If an error related to the scope, please add the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and authorize the scopes again and test it again.

#### Reference:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)

Comment: thank you for your help. Unfortunately script is not working for me. When I have new file in my local folder and this file Is NOT in google drive folder I got an error : 
`HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "File not found: 1z_pUvZyt5AoTNy-aKCKLmlNjdR2OPogI.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'File not found: 1z_pUvZyt5AoTNy-aKCKLmlNjdR2OPogI.', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'fileId'}]">`

Comment: Script is uploading CSV and deleting old CSV but not uploading a CSV which was NOT in Google Drive and gives me that error ;(

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `When I have new file in my local folder and this file I not in google drive folder I got an error : ` HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/… returned "File not found: 1z_pUvZyt5AoTNy-aKCKLmlNjdR2OPogI.".`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my proposed script, in that case, the CSV file of local PC is uploaded to Google Drive. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. About `Script is uploading CSV and deleting old CSV but not uploading a CSV which was NOT in Google Drive and gives me that error ;(`, when I tested my proposed script, in the case of such the situation, the CSV file is uploaded. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill. I would like to study more. But, now, I would like to correctly understand your situation. I would be grateful if you can forgive my very poor skill.

Comment: you are helping me so much, please don't apologize for nothing man :p

Comment: hmm.. on my side the script is not working and gives me error when there is new file in local folder :(

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. About `hmm.. on my side the script is not working and gives me error when there is new file in local folder :(`, I apologize for the inconvenience again. When I tested my proposed script using a new file in local PC, the console shows `No files found.` and `File was uploaded. The file ID is ###fileId of uploaded file###`. So, I cannot replicate your situation. So, in order to correctly understand your situation, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer About `you are helping me so much, please don't apologize for nothing man`, thank you for it. But, the reason that my proposed script doesn't work in your environment while no issue occurs when I tested my proposed script is due to my very poor skill. In this case, I think that I have to deeply apologize for my very poor skill and have to study more. In the current stage, I would like to try to replicate your issue.

Comment: I am doing everything like you. Add new csv to local folder and then I also got "file not found" but then I get 

`HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "File not found: 19vrbvaeDqWcxFGwPV82APWYTmBMEn-hi.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'File not found: 19vrbvaeDqWcxFGwPV82APWYTmBMEn-hi.', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'fileId'}]">`

Comment: thank you one more time for your time:) When I delete rows witch delete old spreadsheets: `oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0], filePath)
        print(oldSpreadsheetId)
        sh = gc.del_spreadsheet(oldSpreadsheetId)` the script is working and is uploading the new file but then of course the script is not deleting old files in google drive. There is some problem with deleting the old files..

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: ok, thank you for help. I have no idea why it is not working for me. I have a question. Do you know how to change the script to just delete ALL files that are in the google drive folder? It would be workoaroung for me for now.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer About `I have a question. Do you know how to change the script to just delete ALL files that are in the google drive folder? It would be workoaroung for me for now.`, in your new question, if you want to know YES or NO, it's YES. If you want a sample script, can you post it as a new question? Because this is different from your question. By this, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I have made new question. Your help means really a lot for me. I can learn much faster right now just reading your solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599790/google-api-python-empty-folder-in-google-drive-before-uploading-new-files

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. I will check your new question. When I have a question, I will comment it.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer From your new question, in this question, can you modify `file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id").execute()` to `file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id", supportsAllDrives=True).execute()` and test it again. I thought that in your situation, `supportsAllDrives=True` might be required to be used.

Comment: it is working! It is working but I still got error `list index out of range kernel crashed`

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue of `list index out of range kernel crashed`, in this case, where does the error occur in my proposed script?

Comment: the error occurs after the new file from local folder (CSVtoGD) is uploaded. So the script is working correctly from the begging to end but I also got this weird error.

Comment: `info 11:20:37.464: Execute Cell 0 /Users/user/Untitled-1.ipynb
info 11:21:49.326: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
info 11:21:49.326: Cancel pending cells
info 11:21:49.326: Cell 0 executed with state Error`

Comment: `IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/zw/12ns4dw96zb34ktc_vfn0zp80000gp/T/ipykernel_6051/4082524706.py in <module>
     38     fname = filename.split(".")
     39     if fname[1] == "csv":
---> 40         oldSpreadsheetId = getSpreadsheetId(fname[0], filePath)`

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. About `the error occurs after the new file from local folder (CSVtoGD) is uploaded.`, I couldn't understand the error line in my proposed script. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: the error occur after script is finished. It deletes old files from google drive, uploads all new files and then there is the error

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. About `the error occur after script is finished. It deletes old files from google drive, uploads all new files and then there is the error`, in this case, an error occurs after the loop was finished. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, exactly. Error is after the loop. In your other script in question I have posted, it is working great without error

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. About `yes, exactly. Error is after the loop. In your other script in question I have posted, it is working great without error`, in this case, when `print("sample")` is added to the last line of my proposed script, you can see `sample` in the console? If you cannot see `sample`, I thought that the error might occur in the loop.

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer If you can see `sample` in the console, how about replacing `print("sample")` with `exit()`?

Comment: @ I can't see the "sample" after I added the line

Comment: @script is crashing and no "sample" is visible

Comment: @Kamilminiprogramer Thank you for replying. From `I can't see the "sample" after I added the line`, it is considered that your `yes, exactly. Error is after the loop. In your other script in question I have posted, it is working great without error` was not correct. In this case, can you provide the error line in my proposed script? Because, when I tested my proposed script, I cannot confirm your error message. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again.